# Is there a good python module that does HTML encoding/escaping in C?

Tags: python, escaping, python-module

There is cgi.escape but that appears to be implemented in pure python.  It seems like most frameworks like Django also just run some regular expressions.  This is something we do a lot, so it would be good to have it be as fast as possible.

Maybe C implementations wouldn't be much faster than a series of regexes for this?

Comment: What's the question?  Are you asking if C is faster than the Python regex library?  Isn't this pretty much self-evident?  Or do you want to know how much faster?  Or do you want to know if regex parsing of URLs is the bottleneck in Django?  What's the question?

Comment: Using a series of regexes is not just slower -- it's *wrong*. Parsing SGML subsets correctly is surprisingly difficult to do correctly in 100% of cases, and ad-hoc regular expressions are not the right tool for the job.

Comment: For just replacing &/</>/", regex is capable enough. But then so is plain old string.replace, which is what cgi.escape uses. You likely aren't going to get much faster... certainly not faster enough ever to be noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), which is based on [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/). While it's primarily a XML library, [HTML support is available](http://codespeak.net/lxml/parsing.html#parsing-html).